# "You don't have permission to access / on this server" в произвольном каталоге

Tags: ubuntu, apache

При загрузке localhost должна загружаться страница, расположенная в любой папке.

[image: Файл описания конфига стандартного сервера]

При замене папки в DocumentRoot на свою браузер выдает ошибку доступа:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Права доступа папок и html файла менял на 777, 775, 770, 644, но ошибка не пропала. Все действия сервера запускались через sudo. Замена пути на любую свою папку в разделе `/etc/apache2/www/html` работает хорошо.

Какие права доступа поставить своей директории, чтобы при загрузке localhost сервер выдавал бы мою страничку?

Comment: apache как правило запускается от имени www-data, и у www-data должен быть доступ к вашей директории. самое просто это добавить www-data в группу вашего юзера

Comment: текстовую информацию логично и правильно приводить в виде текста, а не в виде картинки.

Answer (score 1):

> При замене папки в DocumentRoot на свою браузер

как я понял, подразумевается каталог `/test/www/html`. если этот каталог **действительно** существует, то, вероятно, в нём не хватает индексного файла. например, `index.html`.